# iOS7 segue without using Storyboards

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, pass-data

I have a app with `UITableView` (in `PatientViewController`) and every click on different cells should send different values to the `ArticleViewController`. I made every transition between `ViewControllers` with this code:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
NewsViewController *mv = (NewsViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"news"];
[self presentViewController:mv animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I didn't want to use `NavigationController` and don't want to use Storyboard to create segue. So how can I do it with only writing code, without using Storyboard? Thank you.

Comment: What container you are using ? Do you want to have custom animations or UINavigationController style ?

Comment: I have a UIViewController extending UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. It has a tableview and a custom cell named "Cell". Animations and NavController are not my concern. As you know we are doing right-click-drag from the button to the other view controller to create a segue on Storyboard. **I don't want it** All I want to do is create a segue on tableviewcell click, without using StoryBoard just with coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a UIStoryBoardSegue with the following :

```
  UIStoryboardSegue :: initWithIdentifier:source:destination:
```

and then, from the source `UIViewController`, can call the following:

```
 performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
```

For details, refer to Overview section of UIStoryBoardSegue documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NewsViewController *nVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"news"];
[self presentViewController:nVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make any view controller through Storyboard, make a view controller with XIB. then, call the following method to init an instance.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

When a cell is selected, you can use the following method to present a view controller that you want to show.

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```